# Unified Functional Test GitHub integration

Tags: hp-uft

Hi Am using Unified Functional Test 12 version. 
But Unable to get GIT HUB integration. Any one here have inputs on it

Answer (score 1):

Am attaching a screenshot of compatibility matrix. It seems your Version 12 don't supports GitHub integration. Kindly check the image and match the compatibility of both the tools.

Happy to help :-)[image]